# Homomorphism between hyperboloid and lightcone

Tags: group-theory

The Lorentz group $O(1,D-1)$ is the set of all transformations that preserve the quadratic form $p^2 = \eta_{\mu\nu} p^\mu p^\nu$ with $\eta_{\mu\nu} = (-1,+1,+1,\cdots,+1)$. The surfaces
$$
H = \{ p \in {\mathbb R}^{1,D-1} | p^2 = -1, p^0 > 0\}
$$
and
$$
L = \{ q \in {\mathbb R}^{1,D-1} | q^2 = 0 , q^0 > 0\}
$$
are both preserved under proper Lorentz transformations $\Lambda \in O^\uparrow (1,D-1)$.

More precisely, under Lorentz transformations,
$$
p^\mu \mapsto \Lambda^\mu{}_\nu p^\nu  , \qquad q^\mu \mapsto \Lambda^\mu{}_\nu q^\nu . 
$$
where $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ is a Lorentz transformation matrix so it satisfies $\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta$.

Does there exist an invertible map $f: H \to L$ such that
$$
f(p) = q \implies f(\Lambda p) = \Lambda q, \qquad p \in H , \qquad q \in L 
$$
for *all* $\Lambda\in O^\uparrow (1,D-1)$.

Comment: Well, you can map the upper half of both to the horizontal hyperplane by forgetting the first coordinate. I'm not sure though about your condition on $f$, can you clarify?

Comment: @Berci - I added some details to my question. I hope it helps. The map that forgets the first coordinate does not preserve the condition I wrote.

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ fixed in $f(\Lambda p)=\Lambda q$ or which quantifiers would be used? Anyhow, I think you'll have troubles around $0$ in $L$.

Comment: @Berci - 0 is not in $L$ since we need $q^0 > 0$. $p$ and $q$ are not fixed. The map $f$ maps $p$ to $q$ so $f(p) = q$ and $f(\Lambda p) = \Lambda q$. I'll add this to the question. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: @Berci - I'm also happy if $f$ maps between dense subsets of $H$ and/or $L$ as long as its "almost all" elements of either set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such isomorphism.

First, let's consider the case $D>2$. For $p\in H$, let $\Lambda_p\in O^\uparrow (1,D-1)$ be some element which maps $p$ to $(1, 0\dots, 0)$. Then for any rotation $R\in SO(D-1)$ (here I embed $SO(D-1)$ into $O^\uparrow (1,D-1)$ in the usual way, as the subgroup of elements whith preserve the 0th coordinate),
$$
\Lambda_p^{-1}R\Lambda_p f(p) = f(\Lambda_p^{-1}R\Lambda_p p) = f(p),
$$
which means that $R\Lambda_p f(p) = \Lambda_p f(p)$, i.e., $\Lambda_p f(p)$ is a point on $L$ preserved by all rotations. But $L$ does not contain such a point.

And if $D=2$, then $L$ consists of two rays, and every element of $O^\uparrow (1,D-1)$ preserves each ray. Let $p_1, p_2\in H$ be such that $f(p_1)$ and $f(p_2)$ belong to different rays. Let $B$ be the boost which maps $p_1$ to $p_2$. Then we get $Bf(p_1) = f(p_2)$, which is impossible.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!